# Why Github expects a status check to Require branches to be up to date before merging?

Tags: git, github

This is a follow up of this question:
[Enforce up-to-date pull requests on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757142/enforce-up-to-date-pull-requests-on-github)

I'd like to ensure that a branch is up to date (to master) before merging
so that Github avoid mergin branches that are behind master

But from configs  I read:

No status checks found
Sorry, we couldn’t find any status checks in the last week for this repository.

Then the link to documentation on how status API works.

Question is:

is there some easy way to protect master branch from unwanted PR
without setting up status check,
or some quick way to just check if a branch is behind master before being merged?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for certain, but I believe the feature is designed to make sure that the code that's merged passes tests.  For example, a pull request which is out of date might merge cleanly, but contain a logical conflict that broke one or more of the items in the testsuite.

I don't believe the feature is intended to prevent branches that are simply behind from being merged, since in general there are few downsides to doing so unless you're doing some sort of testing.  Git's merge algorithms are typically robust.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. And I agree with you that merge algorithms are robust in terms of conflicts. But do you agree that sometimes two concurrent PR might overlap e.g. some semantic code issues that cant be detected by code conflicts checks simply? So granting that one's PR is up to date help unwanted behaviour. Statuses checks apart

Comment: I agree that's the kind of thing you might want to check in a code review, but presumably you have automated tests to check that as well, which is why the feature exists.  If you have no tests, then you're going to miss a large number of issues in general.